# When I borrow money, do I ever have to pay it back?

Tags: incremental-zoo

Is there any downside to borrowing money? It seems that the more I borrow, the more my credit limit goes up, and I can just keep on getting more. Am I being charged interest? Will I ever be forced to give it back?

Comment: If you go over your Credit Limit, I believe you are unable to buy anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don't make money from nothing. You borrow it, and later you'll have to pay with interest (or the game will stop).

So basically if you borrow you will have to pay with interest, and you will be forced to pay it back or else the game stops. Wouldn't that be something if you could borrow without any interest and never had to pay back!

[**Source**](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/1wn2wh/incremental_zoo_a_new_game/)